# Get All Collection data from app write using php

Tags: php, appwrite

I am using Appwrite PHP SDK to query a collection that has more than 25 documents. I want to get all the documents in one query, so I tried to set the limit parameter like this:

```
$query = [
'limit' => 10 // Set the query limit to retrieve only 10 records
];

$staff_member_permissions = $databases->listDocuments('6421819e68517dc04814', '6422a0ea9c35c00f9e6c',$query);
```

However, this does not work and I still get only 25 documents. How can I get all the documents in one query using Appwrite PHP SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting only 25 result becuase that's the default limit.
Reference:
https://appwrite.io/docs/queries

For what I know, you can't query "unlimited" documents.
If I remember, max limit is 5000...you can pass 5000 as parameter to limit.

Reference:
https://appwrite.io/docs/client/databases?sdk=web-default#databasesListDocuments

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer there may be a max limit allowed for a single query, but you are also not passing the query parameter in the expected way. From the documentation you should use the `Query` class from the SDK.

In this case to set the limit, you may need to instead add `Query::limit(10)` to your queries array, like this:

```php
// Use the Query class...
use Appwrite\Query;

$query = [
  Query::limit(10), // Set the query limit to retrieve only 10 records
];
```

More details on the [Queries can be found in the docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/queries).

EDIT: Looking at the issues, there seems to be confusion around how to use queries, you may want to reference [this issue](https://github.com/appwrite/sdk-for-php/issues/12) where the syntax is a bit different:

```php
use Appwrite\Query;

$q = new Appwrite\Query();

$query = [
  $q->limit(10), // Set the query limit to retrieve only 10 records
];
```

---

You can try increasing that limit, but if you find that you need to retrieve more than the max allowed you will likely have to paginate your request. There is [an example of how to do that with the use of limit and offset here](https://appwrite.io/docs/pagination). This is the example provided for the Node Client SDK:

```php
import { Databases, Query } from "appwrite";

const client = new Client()
    .setEndpoint("https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1")
    .setProject("[PROJECT_ID]");

const databases = new Databases(client);

// Page 1
const page1 = await databases.listDocuments(
    '[DATABASE_ID]',
    '[COLLECTION_ID]',
    [
        Query.limit(25),
    ]
);

const lastId = page1.documents[page1.documents.length - 1].$id;

// Page 2
const page2 = await databases->listDocuments(
    '[DATABASE_ID]',
    '[COLLECTION_ID]',
    [
        Query.limit(25),
        Query.cursorAfter(lastId),
    ]
);
```

You could translate that to PHP and if needed turn it into a loop of some kind to iterate through the results instead of hardcoding the pages.